# Detect duplicates with COUNTIFS in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a lookup table with duplicate task names, but that's ok so long as the lookup value (Bucket) is the same across the duplicate entries. What I'm trying to figure out is how to write a true/false that flags all members of the duplicate record that are assigned to inconsistent buckets.

[image: Goal image example]

I've tried using `CountIf` functions but I keep running afoul of situations like the first four rows in the picture, where the inconsistency occurs multiple times across multiple rows. My formula is:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)>1),"Incon‌​sistent","Consistent‌​")
```

***EDIT: Example of where I'm currently stuck, highlighting shows what situation defeats my logic***
[image: Sticking point]

Comment: Can you explain when you need True and which formula did you try? Do you Want TaskName1 with Bucket1 to result True and TaskName1 with Bucket2 to be False?

Comment: I'm hoping to get ALL entries with TaskName1 to show true when the inconsistency exists between any of the TaskName1 duplicates and their respective buckets.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make this column filterable so I can see all task names that are a.) duplicate and b.) have inconsistent buckets.

Comment: The formula I tried was
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)>1),"Inconsistent","Consistent")
...where A is the TaskName column, and B is the Bucket, and I'm testing for a.) duplicate task names then b.) duplicate task name/bucket combos.

Comment: In your example TaskName4 is the only consistent?

Comment: In the first photo, TaskName4 and TaskName3 would both qualify as consistent. TaskName4 because it's not a duplicate, and TaskName3 because all duplicates are assigned to the same bucket (Bucket3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your formula to this

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)<COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

which says if there are fewer rows matching both Taskname and Bucket than there are matching Taskname alone, then it is inconsistent.

Shorter would be

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)>0
```

which says there is at least one non-matching bucket for the same Taskname.

Comment: Blown away - thanks! It works, but the part I'm still struggling to understand, is how does Excel determine its context? How does it know to only look at Buckets within a given TaskName's duplicates? Or is that just build into the CountIfs logic and how it evaluates the B2 vs. B:B clause?

Comment: Yes it's built into the COUNTIFS - e.g. for the first task the A:A part limits it to the four rows matching TaskName1 and the B:B part picks out of those the two rows matching Bucket1 in the first formula (or not matching Bucket1 in the second formula).